# Was is true use Context and Redux in single project?

Tags: reactjs, redux

i'm use redux for my project. And i make registration and login with context( Save user and token with check logged in). It's true or remove context and use only redux?

Comment: Please include additional details. What have you done and following which approach of reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already use Redux, stick to that, multiple global state/store is hard to manage.